# how do we get last inserted id respectively if we have multiple shop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have been making a inventory system for multiple shops. all data inserting into the one table

how do we get last inserted id based on the shops

For example, 3 peoples selling the stock from the different pc at same time, if we take last inserted id, which id would return, I need to get the respective id for each shop

Model:

```
public function Save_buyer_info($buyer_information)
{
    //$email= $this->session->userdata('email');
    // print_r($buyer_information);
    $this->db->insert('live_sale_buyers',$buyer_information);   
    return $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function submit_order()
{
    //$data=$this->input->post();
    $name = $this->input->post('txt_name');
    $emailBuyer = $this->input->post('txt_email');
    $number = $this->input->post('txt_number');
    $address = $this->input->post('txt_address');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $payMode = $this->input->post('payment_mode');

    $email = $this->session->userdata('email'); // get shop id
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $activeUser = $this->db->get('live_sale_users');
    $a = $activeUser->row_array();
    $shopId = $a['shop_id'];

    $buyer_information = array(
        "name" => $name,
        "email" => $emailBuyer,
        "mobile" => $number,
        "address" => $address,
        "done_by" => $username,
        "paymentmode" => $payMode,
        'shop_id' => $shopId,
        'shop_keeper_email' => $email
    );

    $buyer_id = $this->Query_Inventory->Save_buyer_info($buyer_information);
}
```

Table structure:
[image: Table structure]

Comment: [Use a transaction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), you'll then get the correct ID...

Comment: What have you tried to get the ID? Is there anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 1):

On login get the shop name or shop id and store it in session variables.
While getting last inserted id,get the session shop id and also return current time on inserting data.This will make sure that the last inserted id from which shop and which time